# Create checkbox array in form_for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, select, checkbox, form-for

I have this _form file.

```
<%= form_for(@company) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.label :company_type %>
  <%= f.select :company_type_id, CompanyType.order(:name).map{|x| [x.name, x.id]} %>        
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

My question is how do I change select

```
<%= f.select :company_type_id, CompanyType.order(:name).map{|x| [x.name, x.id]} %>
```

in this form into checkbox list?

CompanyType model:

```
class CompanyType < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :companies
end
```

Company model:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :company_type_id, :website
  belongs_to :type, :class_name => "CompanyType", :foreign_key => :company_type_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= f.check_box :company_type_id, CompanyType.order(:name).map{|x| [x.name, x.id]} %>
```

Comment: sorry, I just edit the answer, the solution is proposed by @Ganesh ;)

Comment: @tkanzakic it still doesn't work. It says "undefined method `merge' for [["Oil", 3], ["Finance", 2], ["IT", 1]]:Array"

Answer (score 0):

Try the checkboxes_select method

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes